# Unable to execute query using mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am unable to execute query

```
if (!mysql_query("SELECT `title`,LEFT(`description`,70) as `description`,`url`
                  FROM `articles` 
                  WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%blog%'"))
{
    echo 'Failed';
}
```

If I copy and run the same query directly into SQL menu of localhost, it runs successfully.

Comment: maybe its not related to the query. have you checked whether the connection to the server is made. can you post the full php code that has this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not using this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `title`,LEFT(`description`,70) as `description`,`url`
              FROM `articles` 
              WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%blog%'") or die (mysql_error());
                                                      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---better use this instead of "failed" to debug, if want change it do it like that **or die ('failed');**
```

it works like the if ,it will be interpreted like that :

> execute my query please  [image] or if its not true my query please die and echo the error.

---

> This cant be used  in production but only during development for not passing technical error messages to the user, can give them important hints on detecting and/or exploiting vulnerabilities

Comment: Omg if you see my heart what is saying : **echo (' me toooo :) ! ') ; or die(dont lie :( !)**

Comment: hehehe i love echo i want echo everything :) .

Comment: return "Love you too";

Comment: This should not be use in production but only during development; passing technical error messages to the user can give them important hints on detecting and/or exploiting vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your MySQL connection is not setup well. Is your `mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass)` ok? Have you selected the right database using `mysql_select_db()`?

Comment: Yes, database was not selected.